How to solve for bounds restricting ${\Sigma}$ to symmetric-positive-semi-definiteness?
Scenario
I have a equation for a covariance matrix ${\Sigma}$ where everything but a vector of correlations is known aka $x=(x_{1}, \dots, x_{D})$ for  $x_{i}\in [-1, 1]$.
Problem
I know that ${x}$ must have some constraints on it to ensure that ${\Sigma}$ is a valid covariance matrix (i.e., that it is symmetric positive-semi-definite) but I can't figure out how to solve for those constraints -- that is, I am looking for some type of inequality for ${x}$ (parameterized by the other terms on the right hand side of the following equation) that ensures that ${\Sigma}$ is a valid covariance matrix.
Equation
${\Sigma} = {\Gamma} + {a} (\gamma \circ x) {\mathbf{1}^{T}} + a \mathbf{1} (\gamma \circ x)^{T} + {a^2} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{T}$

${\Gamma}$ is a known symmetric positive-definite matrix
${\gamma}$ are the corresponding standard deviations as a vector (e.g., ${\gamma_{i}} = {\sqrt{\Gamma_{ii}}})$
${\alpha}$ is a known positive-valued scalar $(a \in [0,\infty))$.
${\mathbf{1}}$ denotes a length ${D}$ vector of ones
${\circ}$ denotes the elementwise (Hadamard) product.

My attempt
I tried to placing this middle matrix, which is symmetric of rank 2 but can be either positive negative or 0 eigenvalues, into a simpler form ${M} = {a} (\gamma \circ x) {\mathbf{1}^{T}} + a \mathbf{1} (\gamma \circ x)^{T} $ into ${M} = {V}{\mathbf{1}^{T}} + {\mathbf{1}}{V}^{T}$ where V is a vector and then solving for the eigenvalues. I cant figure out and interpretable closed form solution for $\lambda_{min}$. I know that there is no upper bound for the ${x_i}$, but there must be a lower or at least that is what numerical simulation tells me.
Any help or advise would be most appreciated!

Just to clarify, are you asking about the minimal eigenvalue of $M$ or of $\Sigma$?

For my attempt, I tried finding an interpretable closed form expression for ${\lambda_{min}}$ of ${M}$, but my goal is to figure out the bounds of ${x}$ to restrict ${\Sigma}$ to symmetric positive semi definite.

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $W$ be the matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $v_i + v_j$. Then the matrix $W$ has two non-trivial eigenvalues which are given by
$$
\left(\sum_i v_i\right) \pm \sqrt{d} \sqrt{\sum_i v_i^2}
$$
and have corresponding eigenvectors whose $k$-th entry is
$$
\left(\sum_i v_i^2\right) \pm \sqrt{d}(v_k-v_d)\sqrt{\sum_i v_i^2} - d v_k v_d \,.
$$
In particular this implies that the minimum eigenvalue of $W$ is $\min\{0, \left(\sum_i v_i\right) - \sqrt{d} \sqrt{\sum_i v_i^2}\}$.
Now consider the following identity, for two Hermitian matrices $A,B$ we have $\lambda_{\min}(A+B) \geq \lambda_{\min}(A) + \lambda_{\min}(B)$. Thus for your problem we have
$$
\lambda_{\min}(\Sigma) \geq \lambda_{\min}(\Gamma + a^2 11^T) + \lambda_{\min}(M).
$$
This gives the following sufficient condition on $x$ such that $\Sigma$ is PSD
$$
\sum_{i} \gamma_i x_i - \sqrt{d} \sqrt{\sum_i \gamma_i^2 x_i^2} \geq -\frac{1}{a} \lambda_{\min}(\Gamma + a^2 11^T)
$$

thanks for this, double checked it computationally. I cant figure out how you came up with the expression for the eigenvalues. Do you mind helping me out with the intuition/derivation of the expression?

Nothing special, solved $d \in {2,3,4}$, conjectured a general expression and then verified it was really an eigensystem of $W$.
